# Unit testing a form element with Jasmine and Karma in AngularJS for $setPrisrine()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I have a input form element as below in my HTML:

```
<form name='myForm'>
    <input type="text" id="description" name="description"
           ng-model="vm.description" />
</form>
```

And I set it pristine as below in my controller by its name.

```
$scope.myForm.description.$setPristine();
```

How can I write a unit test to check if the input is being set to pristine or not?

Comment: Ideally you will be just testing whether $setPristine method should get called on the form element in unit test based on the scenario